# what does this javascript mean

Tags: javascript

I've got a script like below

```
       qq.UploadHandlerForm = function(o){
        this._options = {
            action: '/upload',
            onComplete: function(id, fileName, response){}
        };
        qq.extend(this._options, o);

        this._inputs = {};
    };

qq.UploadHandlerForm.prototype = {
    add: function(fileInput){
        fileInput.setAttribute('name', 'qqfile');
        var id = 'qq-upload-handler-iframe' + qq.getUniqueId();       

        this._inputs[id] = fileInput;

        // remove file input from DOM
        if (fileInput.parentNode){
            qq.remove(fileInput);
        }

        return id;
    },
    upload: function(id, params){                        
        var input = this._inputs[id];

        if (!input){
            throw new Error('file with passed id was not added, or already uploaded or cancelled');
        }                

        var fileName = this.getName(id);

        var iframe = this._createIframe(id);
        var form = this._createForm(iframe, params);
        form.appendChild(input);

        var self = this;
        this._attachLoadEvent(iframe, function(){            
            self._options.onComplete(id, fileName, self._getIframeContentJSON(iframe));

            delete self._inputs[id];
            setTimeout(function(){
                qq.remove(iframe);
            }, 1);
        });

        form.submit();        
        qq.remove(form);        

        return id;
    },
    cancel: function(id){        
        if (id in this._inputs){
            delete this._inputs[id];
        }        

        var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
        if (iframe){
            iframe.setAttribute('src', 'javascript:false;');

            qq.remove(iframe);
        }
    },
    getName: function(id){
        // get input value and remove path to normalize
        return this._inputs[id].value.replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, "");
    },  
    _attachLoadEvent: function(iframe, callback){
        qq.attach(iframe, 'load', function(){
            if (!iframe.parentNode){
                return;
            }
            if (iframe.contentDocument &&
                iframe.contentDocument.body &&
                iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML == "false"){
                return;
            }

            callback();
        });
    },
    _createIframe: function(id){
        var iframe = qq.toElement('<iframe src="javascript:false;" name="' + id + '" />');
        iframe.setAttribute('id', id);

        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);

        return iframe;
    },
    _createForm: function(iframe, params){
        var form = qq.toElement('<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>');
        var queryString = '';
        for (var key in params){
            queryString += "/"+ encodeURIComponent(params[key]);
        }

        form.setAttribute('action', this._options.action + queryString);
        form.setAttribute('target', iframe.name);
        form.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(form);

        return form;
    }
};
```

I want to know what the "_" is used for, and what is "_createIframe: function(id){}" called? And what is "getName: function(id)" called ?

Secondly, I want to use the getName inside the "_createForm: function(iframe, params){}". How can I do it? I tried something like

```
 _createForm: function(id,iframe, params){var fn= this.getName(id)}
```

but got an error

---

*EDIT: Adding info that was posted as an answer.*

When I do

```
_createForm: function(iframe, params){
  var fname = this.getName(id);
    }
```

I got error "id is undefined". Then I try

```
 _createForm: function(id, iframe, params){
  var fname = this.getName(id);
    }
```

I got error "this._input[...].value is null or not an object"

Comment: Have you never received a satisfactory answer to any of your questions?

Comment: Now I understand your question El Ronnoco, just ticked the old answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know what the "_" is used for,

The `_` is just the first character in the name.

> ...what is "_createIframe: function(id){}" called? And what is "getName: function(id)" called ?

They are functions that have been assigned to the prototype object for the `UploadHandlerForm` class. They will be accessible to all instances of that class.

> Secondly, I want to use the getName inside the "_createForm: function(iframe, params){}". How can I do it?

From inside `_createForm`, you'd call it like:

```
this.getName('some id');
```

If you're getting an error, you'll need to tell us what the error is.

Comment: @runrunforest: So it appears as though you're successfully calling the `this.getName()` function when you use the `id` parameter, but it isn't finding an `input`. I'd guess that there's something wrong with the `id` you're passing when you call `_createIframe()`. I assume someone else wrote this script. The trouble with adding arguments to a function like you did, is that any other code that calls that function will break. It would be better if you added `id` as the *last* argument. `_createForm: function(iframe, params, id){`, then make sure you're passing a useful `id` when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

the _ is just part of the variable identifier, it doesn't technically mean anything in JS but the might have a special meaning to the developer (eg all variables with _ might do something specific)

_createIframe: function(id){} is part of an object (one-off objects are created like this {} or extended from the JS Object class).  They're using the prototype property to extend one object with another object.

try qq.UploadHandlerForm.getName(...)

Answer (score 0):

The _ is just part of the name, but having _ at the beginning of a name is a common convention for "this stuff is private; you probably shouldn't mess with it".  In Javascript, stuff is implicitly public; you actually have to jump through some hoops (and waste some memory) to get truly private variables.  Instead of doing that, some people give the private stuff a special name and trust that other people won't muck around with it.  (Private variables are themselves really just a convention anyway, in most languages; anyone who really wants to see them can.  JS makes that a lot harder, but in a way that frankly sucks.)

Answer (score 0):

The underscore character is just part of the identifier. Probably used in this case to represent member variables/routines.

`_createForm: function(iframe, params){}`

..is a name-value pair. `_createForm` being the name and the function definition being the value. So the function is called `_createForm`.

I would recommend watching Doug Crockford's series on javascript.

[The Javascript programming language](http://uk.video.yahoo.com/watch/111593/1710507)

[Advanced Javascript](http://video.yahoo.com/watch/111585/1027823)

Answer (score -1):

You're taking the wrong approach here.

If you're new to JavaScript, you should try reading some tutorials first, and not just take the first bit of complex code you see and try to figure it out. You need to understand the basics first and how it all fits together.

Start here:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: Be careful. Some folks here will downvote you for suggesting `w3schools` as a javascript starting point.

Comment: @patrick Thanks for the heads up. I know it's not the best resource, but for someone that seemingly knows nothing about JavaScript, it's an alright starting point.